# Select room with minimal price on city

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 3 table Room, Hotel, City, how can I select one room with minimal price and its `hotel_id` for each city

```
price | hotel_id | city_id
10    | 1        | 1
13    | 4        | 2
44    | 7        | 3 
...

SELECT MIN(price) price, hotel_id, city_id FROM (
 SELECT MIN(room_price1) price, hotel_id, city_id 
    FROM Hotel 
    JOIN  Room USING(hotel_id)
        JOIN City USING(city_id)
    LEFT JOIN Service_hotel_option USING (hotel_id)
    WHERE room_price1 > 0
        GROUP BY hotel_id
    ORDER BY price ASC) t 
GROUP BY city_id
ORDER by city_name, price
```

but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT price, hotel_id, city_id
FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room AS r1 USING (hotel_id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM room AS r2
    WHERE r2.hotel_id = r1.hotel_id AND r2.price < r1.price)
```

This will only select rows from `hotel INNER JOIN room` if there are no rooms to be found that have lower prices.

Comment: I make some inferences here on the schema, so you may need to adjust how you check that rooms are in the same hotel, or where you're pulling room prices. The important part is `WHERE NOT EXISTS (a cheaper room)`

Comment: i need one room for city. this query return min room price for each hotel? not city
this query same to
SELECT MIN(price), hotel_id, city_id FROM Hotel 
 JOIN  Room USING(hotel_id)
GROUP BY hotel_id

Comment: So join to city too. Like I said, whatever you end up selecting in the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` that matches the definition of "lower price" you're looking for.

Comment: if the room price for two rooms on the hotel records are duplicated

Comment: That's true, if there are two identical prices you'd need to define an alternate criterion for which to pick (even if it's as arbitrary as "the one with the lower ID"). That would be a condition like `r2.price < r1.price OR (r2.price = r1.price AND r2.id < r1.id)1.

Comment: `SELECT distinct  room_price1, hotel_id, city_id, city_name
FROM Hotel
INNER JOIN Room AS r1 USING (hotel_id)
JOIN City c1 USING(city_id) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Room AS r2
JOIN Hotel h2 USING(hotel_id)
    WHERE h2.city_id = c1.city_id AND r2.room_price1 < r1.room_price1 )
AND room_price1 > 0
`